# Server redirect causing problems with font files

Tags: css, redirect, fonts, font-face, http-status-code-301

I'm a complete newb when it comes to server side issues so bear with me.

I am a having a problem were my font files are not showing up on one server, but they are showing on a another.

I'm not sure what server is hosting the actual files as I only deal with html/css.

my font declaration is:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Pictos';
    src: url("fonts/pictos-web.eot");
    src: local("?"), url("fonts/pictos-web.woff") format("woff"), url("fonts/pictos-web.ttf") format("truetype"), url("fonts/pictos-web.svg#webfontIyfZbseF") format("svg");
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

.pictos {
    font-family:'Pictos';
    color:#FC6;
}
```

The css file link is:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen,handheld" type="text/css" href="css/global.css">
```

I checked the network tab and the status code was 301(moved permanently) 
There are images that are also being redirected though they are still showing correctly. The same with the styles in the css files.
However, the server is looking for the files at:

```
/css/global.css/fonts/pictos-web.woff/
```

when they should be like this:

```
 /css/fonts/pictos-web.woff
```

The most baffling thing is that the font works correctly in IE 9-7 but not FF, Chrome and Safari.

Comment: Maybe try setting the path to your fonts in the font-face declaration to "/css/fonts/pictos-web.eot" etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

urls in .css files are relative to the css file itself, NOT the document that's using that css file. e.g.

```
page: http://example.com/dir/subdir/index.php
css:  http://example.com/css/styles.css
         containing: url('foo/bar/img.jpg')
```

Given that layout, the browser will try to fetch

```
http://example.com/css/foo/bar/img.jpg
                   ^^^
```

Your css urls should be local absolute, e.g.

```
 url('/foo/bar/img.jpg');
      ^---
```

to ensure that the proper path is done with no browser-level "redirects".

Comment: I have a feeling that if I do add the add the local absolute path it will fix with the redirected server, but then I'll have a problem on the non redirected server. 

The file system looks like:

index.html
css
  |_index.css
  |_fonts
     |__pictos.woff

hence why I used a path relative to the css file.
I don't upload to the server I just contribute via github. So I'm just making sure it won't mess up the server that it works on as well.